# Can't run SQL scripts in Supabase while installing Quivr for first time

Tags: shell, openai-api, supabase, chatgpt-api

I am trying to follow the readme file instructions in order to install Quivr on my local machine through this [link](https://github.com/StanGirard/quivr) for the first time but I am stuck at step 4.

How may I run the following code in SQL given it is a shell command?

```
chmod +x migration.sh
./migration.sh
```

I tried to run it in Supabase SQL snippet and of course it gave me invalid SQL query and I tried to run it in my terminal and it keeps saying command not found for each .sql file in the migrations.sh.

then the rest of the guidelines in Step 4 mentions choosing create_scripts if it is my first time and i can't find any files named as such

I opened the video tutorial and the scripts used in it are removed and not found in this repo, the author says that the tutorial is a little bit outdated and the readme is to be followed but It doesn't seem obvious for me.

Is there something I am getting wrong here? How can I perform step 4 properly and run the SQL queries in Supabase?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the code of the following link:

https://github.com/StanGirard/quivr/blob/main/scripts/tables.sql

or the same code in the file tables.sql inside the folder "scripts" of your local Quivr.

Paste it in Supabase web interface:

SQL Editor -> New query -> New blank query

And then click "Run".

You will see "Success. Now rows returned"